# How to use must filter with range and terms in elasticsearch 1.4.5

Tags: php, elasticsearch, couchbase

I have to find data started from "today" and its "displaystatus" must be zero. I am using this but it will also returns the documents having displaystatus one.

```
$searchParams['index'] = 'events';  
$searchParams['type'] = 'couchbaseDocument';  
$searchParams['from'] = 0;  
$searchParams['size'] = 1000;  
$searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['range']['starttimestamp']['from'] = $today;  
$searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['term']['displaystatus'] = 0;  
$searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['terms']['cat_id'] = $interestIdArray;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about python but something like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {

      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "FIELD": {
                  "gte": ,
                  "lte": 
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "FIELD": "VALUE"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "FIELD": "VALUE"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

should work in marvel.